# Custom Datetime set day to monday

Tags: c#, datetime

Say for instance i have the following `DateTime`:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime("2014-01-15")
```

Now i want to keep the year and month but set the date to the monday in the week that it is currently in?

Ive found similar posts however these assume that the `Datetime` is today and doesnt specify what you could do for a costum `DateTime`.

It could be done with a `while loop`:

```
public static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime dayInWeek, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    DayOfWeek firstDay = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
    DateTime firstDayInWeek = dayInWeek.Date;
    while (firstDayInWeek.DayOfWeek != firstDay)
        firstDayInWeek = firstDayInWeek.AddDays(-1);

    return firstDayInWeek;
}
```

However this seems like alot of trouble and i was wondering if there is a simplier solution?

Comment: _However this seems like alot of trouble_ Would be better if you explain _why_?

Comment: @SonerGönül seems to me that you will be looping alot if your program has a costum datepicker.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: what's the maximum number of times it will loop?

Comment: You could use a difference between DayOfWeek of the given date and Monday. However, this is most likely too much work for too little gain - the while cycle will be fast enough.

Comment: You want to keep the month/year, but what if the first day of the week is a different month/year?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Your right. That could cause trouble..

Comment: @JohnSaunders depends on the end users choices.

Comment: The `while` solution will still work fine, though. And internally, all it does is add a given amount of ticks - addition of integers. Surely your PC can handle adding at most six integers in a loop? And if you did this often enough to make a difference, you most likely have a much bigger issue with your application :D

Comment: @Luaan your right but i was hoping that there was a more delicate solution but it seems there isnt

Comment: There is, but it's comparatively complex code. Given that you want your code to be as readable as possible, it's a bad trade-off (although obviously, this is a method for a helper class so it would just need to be verified once).

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: so what is more important, the beginning of the week or the given month? Or the first day in the month if the first day in the week is in the previous month? You have to specify your requirements.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: it would surprise me if it would loop more than 7 times.

Comment: @JohnSaunders HAHAHA :D Yeah that would surprise me aswell:P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do this without the `while` cycle, I have a method that works:

```
((7 + (int)date.DayOfWeek) - (int)weekStart) % 7
```

This is the amount of days since the `weekStart` (in your case, `DayOfWeek.Monday`). So you could just do this:

```
return date.AddDays(-((7 + (int)date.DayOfWeek) - (int)DayOfWeek.Monday) % 7;
```

Do make sure to make this a helper method, of course. It's quite annoying trying to verify those complex single-line expressions every time they're used.

Still, the `while` solution isn't really going to be a performance issue unless you're doing something very weird with the dates. You shouldn't really bother trying to (performance) optimize code that isn't a bottleneck in your processing. Date pickers usually aren't the bottleneck :)